# Не работает сеть после ребута в некоторых случаях

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, dual-boot, manjaro

Есть комп с относительно новым железом. На нем установлен Linux(в виде Manjaro Linux) и Windows 7(предустановленная). Проблема такова, что всегда после ребута из ОС Windows в Linux Linux перестает видеть интерфейс локальной сети и есстественно сети нет. Помогает выключение ПК и выдергиване из розетки питания. После чего включить питание и все будет норм. При ребуте из Linux в Linux сеть в порядке. При ребуте из Linux в Windows сеть в порядке. Менялись дистрбутивы Linux, проблема сохранялось. Грешу на предустановленную винду, но сносить ее уж больно не хочется.
Куда копать?
P.S. Индикатор LAN сети, питание USB и тд осталтся активными даже после выключения компа(не из сети).
При ребуте из Windows в Linux и сразу же ребутнуть обратно в Windows винда тоже не найдет сеть.

Comment: Попробуй настройки BIOS сбросить.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/546441/454489